# Grant for locking sys user on Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, locking, sys

I would like to know what GRANT is required to block the SYS user, as i have a common user in the database.

GRANT ALTER USER enabled me to block only the SYSTEM, but it returns the error ORA-01031: insufficient privileges when trying to block the SYS account.

I have also tried GRANT SYSOPER, but also without success.

Comment: Why would you even _think_ about blocking SYS?  I'd hope that oracle explicitly hard-coded the software to prevent you from doing so.  SYS is the ultimate admin, like 'root' on a *nix system.  Block that and you risk irretrievably breaking everything.

Comment: Do you just not want anyone to login as SYS?  Why not just change the password?

Comment: I need to block so that neither the DBA's nor any other user can log in remotely.

I know that I can remove the password file from dbs and SYS does not log in anymore, but I just wanted to block it with ALTER USER, even though trying to access it remotely, no one will be able to.

Comment: I remembered that I cannot remove the password file, because if I do that, I will also remove users from DBA's, which they use via KERBEROS for database administration.

Comment: Disallowing _remote_ logins by SYS (or _any_ user _that has been granted SYSDBA) is a good idea.  Disallowing _any_ login by SYS is sheer lunacy.  You disallow _remote_ logins by SYS (or _any_ user _that has been granted SYSDBA) by setting remote_login_passwordfile to none.  This is how it is done.  Looking for another method is like looking for a means to change a flat tire without using a jack, lug wrench, and spare tire.

Comment: Locking the SYS user can't be done. It's required to startup/operate the database in the first place.